# Display string in excel with math operator

Tags: excel, vba

I want to subract 2 numbers. For example 2 numbers are in Cell A1 and A2.
I want to subract them in cell A3. i.e in cell A3 i'll have "=A1-A2"

If A1-A2 is 0 i want to display "Ok!" else i want to display whatever is answer.

But i want to do this without using if condition.
i.e in cell A3 it should be only "A1-A2"

Comment: Doesn't require VBA at all -- just a rather straightforward application of Excel's `IF` function. Read the help on it.

Comment: You can't really do this without an `If` type condition, whether it's in the worksheet as an `IF` function, or processed in `VBA` directly.  Why would you want to not use an `If` anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use `IF`, as stated, you could use a custom number format, like `0;0;"ok"`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
=IF(A1-A2=0,"OK",A1-A2)
```